# How can I create an xml-based mrgman file using ClearCase but without any GUI interaction?

Tags: xml, merge, clearcase

I know one way to find the files that need to be merged: I could use the command `cleartool findmerge -g`; a GUI will then pop up and let me perform the merge. Then I can save the results as a `mrgman` file.

Is there a command that does not require using the GUI, and that can also generate the same file, given all the correct arguments (destination view name, etc.)?

It looks like the `find merge` command can only generate the list of files that need to be merged.  The output would look like:

```
Needs Merge ".\sft\**.cpp" [(automatic) to \main\YYY_integration\XXX_dev\9 from \main\YYY_integration\11 (base also \main\YYY_integration\XXX_dev\9)]
```

But I want the output file to be an `.XML` file like those generated by the GUI.

Answer (score 1):

You can at least start view [`cleartool findmerge -print`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_7.1.2/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_findmerge.htm).
That will list the files and folders that need merging.

That won't be xml-formatted though, which means a bit of post-processing is required to wrap it in an xml format.

If a folder needs merging, it won't list the files from within that folder.

> You can use the following procedure to guarantee that the log file produced by `findmerge -print` includes all the required file-level merges within the directory tree under srcdir:
>
> Actually perform all the directory-level merges:

```
cleartool findmerge srcdir -type d -merge
```

> Generate a log file that contains the findmerge commands required for files within the merged directory hierarchy:

```
cleartool  findmerge srcdir -type f -print
```